# Detailed mechanism of the cause of diabetes mellitus type 1?

Tags: cell-biology, physiology, zoology, pathology

I have read in some texts that diabetes mellitus type 1 is caused by degeneration of beta cells due to our body's own immune reaction.Is it true? Can you explain further how are such types of immune reactions are induced? And are there any other causative factors known?

Comment: It can be true of diabetes mellitus type I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diabetes mellitus is divided into four  type 1, type 2, gestational diabetes, and specific type of diabetes. Type 1 diabetes is commonly called as Juvenile diabetes or Brittle diabetes.
It is also called as "Insulin-dependent diabetes mellitus (IDDM)". For our bad-luck the causes of Type 1 diabetes remains obscure, and scientists believes its mostly related to genetics and other environmental factors like mutations or virus attacks. I found some articles that may help.

> But it
>   is believed that genetic and environmental factors (possibly viruses)
>   may be involved. The aetiology ('cause') of type 1 diabetes is
>   unknown, but a good deal is known about its pathogenesis (the way in
>   which it develops). As with other complex diseases, the outcome is
>   determined by the interplay of multiple genes and (most likely)
>   multiple environmental determinants, together with an element of
>   happenstance. The risk of developing diabetes is strongly influenced
>   by genes affecting immune function, particularly the [HLA system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_leukocyte_antigen),
>   but other factors are involved. The best evidence for this comes from
>   the study of identical twins: if one twin develops diabetes in
>   childhood, the other (who has identical genes) has no more than a one
>   in three chance of developing the disease. Prospective studies in
>   human populations reveal that circulating auto antibodies directed
>   against the [islets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islets_of_Langerhans) typically appear in the first 5 years of life, and
>   may be present for many years (sometimes 20 years or more) before the
>   disease develops. A similar latent period is seen with coeliac
>   disease, and implies that some sort of regulatory balance has been
>   achieved within the immune system, and subsequently lost. This opens
>   the door to the possibility of 're-education' of the immune system by
>   various forms of immune intervention.
>   [Reference](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8SahffUIrC0J:www.diapedia.org/type-1-diabetes-mellitus/pathogenesis%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=in)
>
> The pathogenesis of Diabetes mellitus type 1 shows a strong tendency towards genetic related factors,
>   [image]
>   [Reference](http://link.springer.com/article/10.2165/00063030-200115050-00002#page-1)